# Statistics with Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a command line tool to calculate statistical data and I'm using minitest. `load_data` returns an array of user input. I would like to know why does this test pass when I use the method `concat`, but if I use the `<<` operator the test passes even when empty. Aren't these two the same thing?

```
class Test < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    @collection = DataSet.new
  end
  def test_data_is_not_empty
    assert ! @collection.load_data.empty?
  end
end

class DataSet
  def initialize
    @collected = []
  end
  def append
    print 'Please input a list of data: '
    value = gets.chomp.split(',').map(&:to_f)
    @collected.concat(value) 
  end
end
```

Comment: I know this is an old question, but you could use [statsample](https://github.com/sciruby/statsample) for doing statistics. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-concat):

```
[ "a", "b" ].concat( ["c", "d"] ) #=> [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]
a = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
a.concat( [ 4, 5 ] )
a #=> [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

In your case, it looks like it would be something like

```
@collected.concat( load_data )
```

If load_data is a member of another object, such as `@collection`, then do

```
@collected.concat( @collection.load_data )
```

If you want to append each element `my_data` at a time from *within* load_data, then do

```
@collected << my_input
```

Comment: Hmm, for my example I'm wanting to prompting a user and then entering in a huge pool of data (numbers) separated by commas and then appending this input into collected. I was thinking more along the lines of `append` and or `<<`

Comment: @TheGrayFox You said "`load_data` returns an array of user input." If this is a string, then replace `load_data` with `load_data.split(',')`. If that's not it, then please give an example in your question of what `load_data` returns. Also, give an example of what `@collected` contains so we can see if it's strings, numbers, etc.

Comment: I edited it the best way I could. Hope that helps explain things a bit better.

Comment: So it looks like `load_data` would return an array. In which case `concat` would be the way to go. See the updated answer.

Comment: Could you explain why using the ```<<``` fails the test when the array has been appended to ```@collection```, but using concat passes the test. Aren't these two the same? I'll edit my question.

Comment: `<<` appends a single element. `concat` appends an array.